# How do I represent a null terminated string array in Delphi?

Tags: c, arrays, delphi, null

How can I represent this C code in Delphi?

```c
static char *mylist[] = {"aaa", "bbb", "ccc", NULL};
```

I can create my array as of

```pascal
keywords : array[0..3] of string;
keywords[0] := 'aaa';
keywords[1] := 'bbb';
keywords[2] := 'ccc';
//Compiler error -> E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Pointer' 
keywords[3] := nil;
```

Comment: `null` is `C` - use `nil` in Delphi.

Comment: Oooops I have nill in my code. Edited the post, thank you.

Comment: Ah. Well, actually you should just be able to do `pchar` instead of `string`.

Comment: This question is missing information that is relevant. What does the C code do with the array `mylist` after this single line? (How to represent it properly in Delphi depends on how the resulting array is being used. Most of the ways you'd use it don't need that construct at all.)

Comment: Exactly. Question is incomplete.

Comment: I see your point, I'll make a complete question then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char*` in C/C++ is `PAnsiChar` in Delphi, eg:

```
const
  mylist: array[0..3] of PAnsiChar = ('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', nil);
```

Or:

```
var
  mylist: array[0..3] of PAnsiChar;

mylist[0] := 'aaa';
mylist[1] := 'bbb';
mylist[2] := 'ccc';
mylist[3] := nil;
```

Comment: This would be the correct approach if the requirement was interop. Pass such a thing to a different module. Otherwise you would never do this.

Answer (score 2):

In Pascal, arrays and strings are a distinct type from pointers, so you can't assign the nil pointer.

You probably don't need a special token to terminate your array anyway. This is a C idiom.

If you want to loop through your array, simply do this :

```
for word in keywords do
    writeln(word)
```